# Autofac register assembly types

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor, autofac

In Castle, I used to do the following to register types from a different assembly:

```
Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyServer.DAL")
       .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
       .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
```

In Autofac, I change the above code to this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Does it work when you run it?

Comment: The code compiles and executes but I don't think it's correct because I can't access my api anymore (error 500).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027330/how-to-resolve-autofac-instanceperhttprequest) may help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 4):

For UWP correct way is a bit alter:

```
   var assemblyType = typeof(MyCustomAssemblyType).GetTypeInfo();

   builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyType.Assembly)
   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .InstancePerRequest();
```

For each assembly you have take single type that belongs assembly and retrieve assembly's link from it. Then feed builder this link. Repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies doesn't return assemblies of dependent projects. Detailed explanation here [Difference between AppDomain.GetAssemblies and BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477787/difference-between-appdomain-getassemblies-and-buildmanager-getreferencedassembl)

In those cases, we should get those project assemblies individually using any class inside the project and register its types.

```
var webAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var repoAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SampleRepository)); // Assuming SampleRepository is within the Repository project
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(webAssembly, repoAssembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `As`'s predicate overload!
You can get the all of the interfaces with `GetInterfaces` from the given types that ends with `"Repository"` and then select the first interface which they implement and register it.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()[0]);
```