# Autofac cannot resolve class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac

I'm building an application with ASP.Net MVC for the back-end. Autofac is being used for dependency injection. Several components/classes are registered as `InstancePerRequest`. The Entity Framework context and unit of work (just a wrapper that calls `context.SaveChanges()`) are registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. Example code:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DomainModule)))
    .Where(t => t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IFooService<>)))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IFoo<>))
    .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<FooContext>()
    .AsSelf()
    .As<IObjectContextAdapter>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Resolving a class from the container using an explicit scope throws the following exception:

```
{"No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scopein which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself."}
```

Code that triggers the above exception:

```
using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var authOrchestration = scope.Resolve<IAuthOrchestration>();
    apiClient = authOrchestration.GetApiClient(context.ClientId);
}
```

Note that the `IAuthOrchestration` isn't being registered with things like `InstancePerRequest`, so that one should just default to `InstancePerDependency`.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a couple hours now. I've read [these](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/) [two](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) articles. From what I've read, I guess the exception is being thrown due to the scopes that do not match (as described [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#no-scope-with-a-tag-matching-autofacwebrequest)). If someone would be able to explain why I get this error, I'd be very thankful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your `IAuthOrchestration` implementation depends on `IFoo<>` ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Orchestration like the mentioned ``IAuthOrchestration`` depend on services like the ``IFooService`` (renamed that one in the question for clarity). These services depend on repositories and these repositories ultimately depend on the ``FooContext``.

Comment: You cannot begin a new scope like that with InstancePerRequest. The answer in this question should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027330/how-to-resolve-autofac-instanceperhttprequest

Comment: @RobTillie Yeah, had to pass the tag along. So both``AutofacWebRequest`` and ``MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag`` do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IAuthOrchestration` has an indirect dependency on `IFoo` which is registered as `InstancePerHttpRequest`.
To resolve (directly or indirectly) a `IFoo` you have to use a *request* `ILifetimeScope`

You create a `ILifetimeScope` which is not a `RequestLifetimeScope`. To create such `ILifetimeScope`, you can use the `MatchingScopeLifetimeTags`.RequestLifetimeScope` tag.

```
using (var scope = _lifetimeScope
                    .BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag))
{
    var authOrchestration = scope.Resolve<IAuthOrchestration>();
    apiClient = authOrchestration.GetApiClient(context.ClientId);                
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I used the wrong scope. Your suggestion fixes the issue. Thanks!